# vuex правильное использование

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как я понимаю, суть vuex в едином хранилище. Но ведь у Vue уже есть глобальный data()... Я пока не вижу где может пригодиться единое хранилище, так, подгружать в каждом модуле разные данные мне кажется более удобным.

Прошу показать пример, когда глобальное хранилище действительно полезно, а то я пытаюсь применить vuex, но пока сталкиваюсь только с тем, что мне неудобно иметь единое хранилище

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас есть компонент `Page`.
У него есть дочерние `Header`, `LeftSideBar`, `MainContent` и `Footer`.
У `Header` есть дочерний `UserDropdown`.
У `LeftSideBar` есть дочерний `UserAvatar`.
У `Footer` есть дочерний `UserLinks`.

Пользователь авторизуется, в `vuex` пишется инфа о пользователе и `MainContent`, `UserDropdown`, `UserAvatar` и `UserLinks` получают об этом информацию тут же и без лишних телодвижений.

Не нужно прокидывать десяток пропсов, не нужно эмитить наверх никаких событий.
Оно просто работает.

Это первое что в голову пришло для примера. Вложенность чаще всего бывает куда больше.

Answer (score 1):

Например во Vue 3 Composition API можете "немного запутаться" с состояниями. когда в дочерних много-вложенных есть и PROPS и INJECT.
Я пока не перестал использовать VUEX для однозначности всех полученных с сервера данных, но стал использовать для всех! AXIOS ( в Админке например)единую форму (как периспользуемый js))):

```
allAxios (context, payload) {
            return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post('/api/'+payload.route,payload)
                    .then((response) => {
                    if(payload.commit) context.commit(payload.commit, 
                       response.data)
                    resolve(response)
                })
                    .catch(error => {reject(error)})
                })
        }
```